# Toggle display:none style with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the style (second line below) to remove the `display: none;` part when the user clicks on the "Show All Tags" link. If the user clicks the "Show All Tags" link again, I need the `display: none;` text added back in to the "style..." statement.

```
<a href="#" title="Show Tags">Show All Tags</a>
<ul class="subforums" style="display: none; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; ">
```

I've searched here and Google for an example I can apply to my situation. I've found plenty of examples using 2 DIV blocks to show/hide. I really need to do it this way, by modifying the html style element. Does anyone have an example (or provide a link to an example) that does this type of toggle wtih the `display: none` text.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Give your `ul` an `id`,

```
<ul id='yourUlId' class="subforums" style="display: none; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; ">
```

then do

```
var yourUl = document.getElementById("yourUlId");
yourUl.style.display = yourUl.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
```

**IF** you're using jQuery, this becomes:

```
var $yourUl = $("#yourUlId"); 
$yourUl.css("display", $yourUl.css("display") === 'none' ? '' : 'none');
```

Finally, you specifically said that you wanted to manipulate this css property, and not simply show or hide the underlying element.  Nonetheless I'll mention that with jQuery

```
$("#yourUlId").toggle();
```

will alternate between showing or hiding this element.

Answer (score 18):

Give the UL an ID and use the getElementById function:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
    function toggledisplay(elementID)
    {
        (function(style) {
            style.display = style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
        })(document.getElementById(elementID).style);
    }
    </script>

<a href="#" title="Show Tags" onClick="toggledisplay('changethis');">Show All Tags</a>
<ul class="subforums" id="changethis" style="overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; ">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Others have answered your question perfectly, but I just thought I would throw out another way. It's always a good idea to separate HTML markup, CSS styling, and javascript code when possible. The cleanest way to hide something, with that in mind, is using a class. It allows the definition of "hide" to be defined in the CSS where it belongs. Using this method, you could later decide you want the `ul` to hide by scrolling up or fading away using CSS `transition`, all without changing your HTML or code. This is longer, but I feel it's a better overall solution.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/RkQCF/

HTML:

```html
<a id="showTags" href="#" title="Show Tags">Show All Tags</a>
<ul id="subforms" class="subforums hide"><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ul>
```

CSS:

```css
#subforms {
    overflow-x: visible; 
    overflow-y: visible;
}

.hide {
    display: none; 
}
```

Script:

```js
document.getElementById( 'showTags' ).addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    document.getElementById( 'subforms' ).toggleClass( 'hide' );
}, false );

Element.prototype.toggleClass = function ( className ) {
    if( this.className.split( ' ' ).indexOf( className ) == -1 ) {
        this.className = ( this.className + ' ' + className ).trim();
    } else {
        this.className = this.className.replace( new RegExp( '(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)' ), ' ' ).trim();
    };
};
```

Comment: What about `document.getElementById('#potato').classList.toggle('hide')` instead of creating a prototype?

Comment: @JeromeJ `.toggle()` is not a Javascript function (there is a jQuery `.toggle()`). Also, `.getElementById()` will not take hash notation (also jQuery).

Comment: oups about the hash! Though, the `.toggle()` *DOES* exist in JavaScript (I use it on my website) but it has the same effect has `toggleClass` from jQuery, so it is not to be confound with the jQuery's `.toggle()`. jQuery to js alternatives: http://toddmotto.com/is-it-time-to-drop-jquery-essentials-to-learning-javascript-from-a-jquery-background/

Answer (score 3):

LEVEL - I

```js
document.querySelector('.my-btn').addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector('.subforums').classList.toggle("off");
}
```

```css
.off {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Show Tags" class="my-btn">Show All Tags</a>
<div class="subforums off">My text...</div>
```

LEVEL - II

Toggle hide element Id end className...

```
function toggleElem(newElem) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('' + newElem + '');
    var eIdent = (elem != null) ? ('#' + newElem) : ('.' + newElem);
    elem = document.querySelector('' + eIdent + '');
    elem.style.display = (elem.style.display != 'none') ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

You can test directly from this link: https://codepen.io/pedro404/pen/VwmPBee

Comment: This works fine... unless you've got an element that doesn't take well to `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through straight javascript and DOM, but I really recommend learning JQuery.  Here is a function you can use to actually toggle that object.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

*EDIT:  Adding the actual code:*

**Solution:**

HTML snippet:

```
<a href="#" id="showAll" title="Show Tags">Show All Tags</a>
<ul id="tags" class="subforums" style="display:none;overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; ">
    <li>Tag 1</li>
    <li>Tag 2</li>
    <li>Tag 3</li>
    <li>Tag 4</li>
    <li>Tag 5</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript code using JQuery from Google's Content Distribution Network:  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

```
$(function() {
    $('#showAll').click(function(){  //Adds click event listener  
        $('#tags').toggle('slow'); // Toggles visibility.  Use the 'slow' parameter to add a nice effect.
    });
});
```

You can test directly from this link:  http://jsfiddle.net/vssJr/5/

**Additional Comments on JQuery:**

Someone has suggested that using JQuery for something like this is wrong because it is a 50k Library.   I have a strong opinion against that.

JQuery is widely used because of the huge advantages it offers (like many other javascript frameworks).  Additionally, JQuery is hosted by Content Distribution Networks (CDNs) like [Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery) that will guarantee that the library is cached in the client's browser.  It will have minimal impact on the client.

Additionally, with JQuery you can use powerful selectors, adding event listener, and use functions that are for the most part guaranteed to be cross-browser.

If you are a beginner and want to learn Javascript, please don't discount frameworks like JQuery.  It will make your life so much easier.