# Switching between two div elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have the following code for going from div "mainFrameOne" to div "mainFrameTwo". However, it cannot go back to mainFrameOne after changing to mainFrameTwo. And I want it to be able to keep switching back and forth. How would I best accomplish this?

**HTML :**

```
<div id="mainFrameOne">
    <p>mainFrameOne</p>
</div>
<div id="mainFrameTwo" style="display:none;">
    <p>mainFrameTwo</p>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

**JS :**

```
function myFunction() { 
    document.getElementById("mainFrameOne").style.display="none"; 
    document.getElementById("mainFrameTwo").style.display="block"; 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle display:none style with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454079/toggle-displaynone-style-with-javascript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add condition to check if the div is visible then hide it and show the other one if else do the reverse :

```
function myFunction() {
   var mainFrameOne = document.getElementById("mainFrameOne"); 
   var mainFrameTwo = document.getElementById("mainFrameTwo");

   mainFrameOne.style.display = (
       mainFrameOne.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none"); 
   mainFrameTwo.style.display = (
       mainFrameTwo.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none"); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function myFunction() {
   var mainFrameOne = document.getElementById("mainFrameOne"); 
   var mainFrameTwo = document.getElementById("mainFrameTwo");

   mainFrameOne.style.display = (
       mainFrameOne.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none"); 
   mainFrameTwo.style.display = (
       mainFrameTwo.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none"); 
}
```

```html
<div id="mainFrameOne">
    <p>mainFrameOne</p>
</div>
<div id="mainFrameTwo" style="display:none;">
    <p>mainFrameTwo</p>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```