# Hide flexbox child and make visible again

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a simple flexbox scenario - parent, few items etc.

I need to selectively hide one of the child items, which I do using `display: none`.

However, at a later point, I need to reinstate the item visibility - but as what? I It's not a `flex`, and I don't think it's an `inline-flex`, so what is it?

I can't use `display: unset` as it only seems to be moderately supported. Any ideas?

```css
.container {
  margin: 40px;
}

.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox-item {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.flexbox-item:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.hide-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox-item">child</div>
    <div class="flexbox-item hide-item">child</div>
    <div class="flexbox-item">child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle display:none style with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454079/toggle-displaynone-style-with-javascript)

Comment: div are blocks so display:"block"

Comment: How do you hide it, can you share a real time scenario of the situation here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reset it back to `display:block`

```css
.container {
  margin: 40px;
}

.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox-item {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.flexbox-item:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

input:checked+.flexbox-container>.hide-item {
  display: block;
}

.hide-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Toggle This</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox-item">child</div>
    <div class="flexbox-item hide-item">child</div>
    <div class="flexbox-item">child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That simple! I was thinking that setting the display back to block would override the div status as a child of a flex item - but it does seem to work.

Comment: @JohnOhara even inline-block will work or also `initial`  (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496749/8620333)

Answer (score 1):

`.flexbox-container` has `display: flex`.

So all the child elements of `.flexbox-container` are flex-children.

If you add `.hide-item` to one of those child elements, that element now has `display: none`.

If you remove `.hide-item` from that child element it goes back to being a flex-child again.

**Example:**

```
const hiddenChild = document.querySelector('.hide-item');

hiddenChild.classList.remove('hide-item');
```